# Batch Addition From File (+1) Rewrite

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch game, that counts a highscore in a separate file called "Score.txt".
In that file, it reads a number, but when you win the game I want it to be overriden with the next highest number. E.G... 0 is the number, I won the game, now it reads 1.

So far this is my code for the highscore...

```
:Score
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set score=
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Score.txt) do set score=!score! %%i
set /a %score%=%score%+1 
echo %score% >score.txt
exit
```

But "Score.txt" only reads if ECHO is on, after I win.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is because ECHO is off?  It seems as though `!score!` in the 4 line shouldn't be there -- that it should be `score=%%i`.  And that the later `%score%` instances should all be `!score!`.

Comment: See my answer below -- it increments the value in score.txt each time it is run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
:Score
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set score=
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Score.txt) do set score=%%i
set /a score=!score!+1 
echo !score! >score.txt
```

Comment: The expansion is not needed when using SET /A. You could also use `set /a score=score+1`, or better yet `set /a score+=1`

Answer (score 2):

James L.'s answer certainly solves the problem, but doesn't explain why the original didn't work.

As James L. pointed out in his comment, the `!score!` is not needed in the FOR statement, though it is not doing any harm since it is undefined.

Delayed expansion is not needed for this problem.

The reason the original code failed was the first expansion in `set /a %score%=%score%+1`. That statement will create a variable with a number as the name. It should have read `set /a score=%score%+1`, or `set /a score=score+1`, or `set /a score+=1`.

There is an alternate to using FOR /F

```
@echo off
set "score="
<"Score.txt" set /p "score="
set /a score+=1
>"Score.txt" echo %score%
```